# SUM of all result in a huge SELECT including WHERE

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sum

I have an huge SELECT including sub-selects and a lot of stuff... Something like :

```
SELECT a AS A,
b AS B,
c AS C,
d AS D,
(SELECT x FROM y WHERE z) AS E,
(SELECT x2 FROM y2 WHERE z2) AS F,
[...]
price
FROM table
INNER lot_of_tables
WHERE lot_of_filters = lot_of_conditions
```

Is there a way to modify this request to get the total amount of prices selected (including WHERE clause) without using `GROUP BY` ?

Because with Oracle if I use `SUM(price)` I have to add the `GROUP BY` expression ... And I just can't "reproduce" the SELECT ... And overall Oracle doesn't accept alias in GROUP BY clause (...why ?)

**Update :**

Some of you said I wasn't clear enough... And I totally agree ^^
I now have a result like this :

```
+----+---+---+---+---+---+-------+
| A  | B | C | D | E | F | price |
+--------------------------------+
| --- Datas got with filter ---- |
| ------------------------------ |
|________________________________|
```

And I want the SUM of the price of theses datas PLUS the actuals columns ! Like :

```
+----+---+---+---+---+---+-------+------+         
| A  | B | C | D | E | F | price | SUM()|
+--------------------------------+------+
| --- Datas got with filter ---- |14875 |
| ------------------------------ |14875 |
|________________________________|______+
```

OR

```
+----+---+---+---+---+---+-------+------+         
| A  | B | C | D | E | F | price | SUM()|
+--------------------------------+------+
| --- Datas got with filter ---- | NULL |
| ------------------------------ | NULL |
|  N | N | N | N | N | N |  NULL | SUM  |
|________________________________|______+
```

which one is the most efficient ?

Comment: Please update your question to include some sample input data and the expected output data. It looks like you're concerned about further manipulating the results generated by the query in your question, so we only need the sample data for the output of the query, and then what you want the final output to be.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. You can remove all columns from your select clause and replace them by `sum(price)`. Is that already it? Or do you want to preserve some columns? If so, how? Do you want the maximum `a`, the minimum `b`, ... ? Or one row per `a` and `b`? Or do you want to add a total row to the existing rows? Show sample data and expected results to clarify this.

Comment: Sorry wasn't clear enough ... I've updated ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have a query like the following:

```
select 'a' as A,
       (select 1 from dual) as one,
       two,
       price
from dual
     cross join ( select 2 as two from dual union all select 2 from dual)
     cross join ( select 100 as price from dual)
```

that gives:

```
a   1   2   100
a   1   2   100
```

If I understand well, you may need:

```
select 'a' as A,
       (select 1 from dual) as one,
       two,
       price,
       sum(price) over () as sum_price
from dual
     cross join ( select 2 as two from dual union all select 2 from dual)
     cross join ( select 100 as price from dual)
```

that gives :

```
a   1   2   100 200
a   1   2   100 200
```

Comment: `sum(price) over ( partition by 1)`? Isn't that just `sum(price) over ()`?

Comment: @Boneist you're right. It's an old habit of mines, due to an old bug I found when not writing `partition by`. Editing

Comment: This sir ... Is amazing ! `over ()` didn't think it was that simple ! Made my day thanks ;)

Comment: @Seba99 if you're not aware of analytic functions (which is what the `<function> over (...)` construct is known as), then I highly recommend you research them, as they're very useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT a,
       b,
       c,
       d,
       (SELECT x FROM y WHERE z),
       (SELECT x2 FROM y2 WHERE z2),
       [...]
       price,
       t.sum_of_prices
FROM table
CROSS JOIN (
   SELECT SUM(price) AS sum_of_prices
   FROM table
   WHERE lot_of_filters = lot_of_conditions) t
WHERE lot_of_filters = lot_of_conditions
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to avoid `GROUP BY` when you aggregation functions, such as `SUM` and want to include non-aggregated column values.

Wrap your complex `SELECT` query into a CTE expression, like this:

```
;
WITH my_query AS (

    SELECT a,
    b,
    c,
    d,
    (SELECT x FROM y WHERE z) AS x,
    (SELECT x2 FROM y2 WHERE z2) AS x2,
    [...]
    price
    FROM table
    INNER lot_of_tables
    WHERE lot_of_filters = lot_of_conditions

)

SELECT SUM(price)
FROM my_query
```

Comment: `There's no way to avoid GROUP BY ...` - there is: you can use analytic functions if you want to aggregate across multiple rows without collapsing the rows.

Comment: Well, yes, @Boneist is technically correct, but I don't think the the Op wants to go that way, considering he has a very complex query.

Comment: It's possibly semantics then; to me, that sentence read very much as if you were suggesting it wasn't possible at all, ever, rather than just applying to the OP's potential scenario (it's not at all clear what the OP is after, hence why I asked them for more info!), but your comment clarifies it a bit.

Comment: Interesting way ... But do i still have my other columns with this way ?

Answer (score 0):

```
select userid,a,b,c,(select abc from z),(select xyz from z), price, sum(price) 
from table1 inner join table2 on table1.a=table2.a
```

and so on
where filter1 and filter2 and so on

and you want sum(price) for each user id has purchased

if the above one is what you are asking then the answer is YES you will need to group them.

```
select userid,a,b,c,
select abc from z),(select xyz from z),
price, sum(price)
from table1 inner join table2 on table1.a=table2.a
```

and so on
where filter1 and filter2 and so on
group by userid

reference: https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/sum.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use sum () over () as below:

```
SELECT a AS A,
b AS B,
c AS C,
d AS D,
(SELECT x FROM y WHERE z) AS E,
(SELECT x2 FROM y2 WHERE z2) AS F,
[...]
price,
Sum(price) over () as sum_price
FROM table
INNER lot_of_tables
WHERE lot_of_filters = lot_of_conditions
```